# The annotation @EnableSpringDataWebSupport does not work with WebMvcConfigurationSupport?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config, spring-data-commons

I had been using the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter for a while. Since i could not get all the registered interceptors with the method getInterceptors(), i have switched to WebMvcConfigurationSupport, which has lot of default registered Spring Beans like ContentNegotiationManager, ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver usw.

Now i have realised that, the very handy DomainClassConverter (which converts the domain class ids to domain class objects by using a CrudRepository) is not registered by default, although i use the annotation @EnableSpringDataWebSupport on my WebConfig class.

When i define this bean explicitly like this, it works then.

```
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public DomainClassConverter<?> domainClassConverter() {
        return new DomainClassConverter<FormattingConversionService>(mvcConversionService());
    }
}
```

But why EnableSpringDataWebSupport does not work with WebMvcConfigurationSupport?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like configuration classes that extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` directly suffer from [SPR-10565](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10565). The solution, at least for me, is to extend from `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` instead.

If you're overriding individual callbacks in your configuration class you'll likely want to call the superclass' implementation of the callback as well to ensure it's all handled correctly.