# EnableSpringDataWebSupport doesn't seem to work well with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I was successfully using `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` in my Spring Boot app to enable pagination, sorting and stuff. However, at some point, I had to introduce a custom argument resolver and did it with Java config as follows:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport 
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(renamingProcessor());
    }

    @Bean
    protected RenamingProcessor renamingProcessor() {
        return new RenamingProcessor(true);
    } 
}
```

It made my new argument resolver work, however completely broke paging and other features, that were automatically configured by `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport`. I've tried switching `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to alternatives like `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` or `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, but no luck -- pagination fails with the exception:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]:
>   Specified class is an interface

I would appreciate any help or advice how to handle this issue. Similar questions didn't help a lot:

- [The annotation @EnableSpringDataWebSupport does not work with WebMvcConfigurationSupport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088289/the-annotation-enablespringdatawebsupport-does-not-work-with-webmvcconfiguratio)
- [Failed to instantiate Pageable bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057262/failed-to-instantiate-pageable-bean/30058772)
- [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910642/webmvcconfigureradapter-does-not-work)

Comment: You shouldn't need `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` as that is already taken care of by Spring Boot when those classes are found.

Comment: @m-deinum thanks for a quick response. I removed `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` from config class, but result is the same -- pagination doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after some investigation, I figured out the solution (perhaps, not ideal one, but still working -- I'd still be happy to see the "right" resolution for the problem from Spring professionals). What I changed is switching from `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` to `extends HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration` (since we're using HATEOAS). I also updated the overridden `addArgumentResolvers` and now my `MvcConfig` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends HateoasAwareSpringDataWebConfiguration {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        argumentResolvers.add(renamingProcessor());
    }

    @Bean
    protected RenamingProcessor renamingProcessor() {
        return new RenamingProcessor(true);
    }
}
```

The issue with `Pageable` disappeared, and custom `RenamingProcessor` works like a charm.

Hope this answer will help someone who's facing similar issue.